# Useless processes in Ubuntu 14.04 virtual server

Tags: boot, virtualization, services, virtualhost

I've used Ubuntu for my desktop for a quite while now and I have successfully migrated my only CentOS web production server to Ubuntu 14.04 x64 a little over 3 months ago and I couldn't be happier.

It is a virtualized server with few resources in a VMWare like environment.

Aren't there some totally useless services (like acpid - which I understand is for the power button... my VPS doesn't have one) that I could turn off in order to have less processes running?

There must be some others that can be turned off...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my list of services starting at boot, from which I've removed the ones I can't part from :

```
acpid
apport
atd
bootmisc.sh
checkfs.sh
checkroot-bootclean.sh
checkroot.sh
cloud-config
cloud-final
cloud-init
cloud-init-container
cloud-init-local
cloud-init-nonet
cloud-log-shutdown
console-font
console-setup
container-detect
control-alt-delete
cron
dbus
dmesg
dns-clean
failsafe
flush-early-job-log
friendly-recovery
grub-common
hwclock
hwclock-save
irqbalance
kmod
mountall
mountall-bootclean.sh
mountall-net
mountall-reboot
mountall.sh
mountdevsubfs.sh
mounted-debugfs
mounted-dev
mounted-proc
mounted-run
mounted-tmp
mounted-var
mountkernfs.sh
mountnfs-bootclean.sh
mountnfs.sh
mtab.sh
ondemand
passwd
plymouth
plymouth-log
plymouth-ready
plymouth-shutdown
plymouth-splash
plymouth-stop
plymouth-upstart-bridge
pppd-dns
procps
quotarpc
rc
rc-sysinit
rc.local
rcS
resolvconf
rsync
rsyslog
saslauthd
screen-cleanup
setvtrgb
shutdown
systemd-logind
udev
udev-fallback-graphics
udev-finish
udevmonitor
udevtrigger
upstart-file-bridge
upstart-socket-bridge
upstart-udev-bridge
ureadahead-other
wait-for-state
```

Comment: `plymouth` is the GUI boot screen, probably can be disabled - but the other stuff such as `rc*`, `cron` etc will likely be needed by the basic services to keep the system running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of this stuff runs at boot time, but doesn't stay in memory.  It would be better to collect info on what is running from `ps -e`

Comment: You have a point. Should have tought of that before posting. Kudos on your answer!